# Cardano-cli Handshake error after Daedalus update

Tags: cardano-cli, daedalus

After updating Daedalus for the Vasil hardfork, I get the below error when running this cardano-cli command

```
cardano-cli get-tip --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

```
cardano-cli: HandshakeError (VersionMismatch [NodeToClientV_9,NodeToClientV_10,NodeToClientV_11] [12,13])
```

My cardano-cli is still version 1.33.0 but I have already updated Daedalus. Is there anything I need to do on my part after updating Daedalus?

Answer (score 2):

> My cardano-cli is still version 1.33.0 but I have already updated Daedalus.

That is the problem right there. I suspect the `node` that is started by Daedalus is either `1.35.0` or `1.35.1` (ie these releases support the Vasil HF). The `cardano-cli` version needs to match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Daedalus version >= v4.12.0 , the download links can be found [here](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/get-started/wallet/).
In case you see older version, clear the browser cache or open the page in Incognito mode.